# Problem Centering Arrows When Using After Selector

Tags: html, css, angular

Currently I am trying to center my arrows that are created using CSS when I hover over my nav menu. Even though I have set the `margin left and right` to `auto`. It still does not seem to want to center. It could be because of the format of my HTML. I have tried a number of options but none of them seem to have helped.

Please see my HTML and CSS below:

(Unfortunately I cannot seem to re-create my code but I will post it and continue to try and recreate it in the mean time)

```css
#navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: $base-white;
  font-size: 11px;
  z-index: 2;
  border: 1px solid $base-grey;
  height: 50px;
}

.navbar-links {
  margin-left: 10em;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0em 4em 0em 1em;
  min-width: 348px;
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
}

#navbar .navbar-links a {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  color: $base-grey;
  padding: 14px 20px 14px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
}

#navbar .navbar-links a:hover:after {
  content: ' ';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -10px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  text-align: center;
  border-width: 10px 10px 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: $base-grey transparent;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar-links">
  <div class="navbar-dropdown">
    <button class="navbar-drop-btn">
      <div class="navbar-arrow"></div>
    </button>
    <div class="navbar-dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a [routerLinkActive]="['navbar-links-active']" [routerLink]="['insights']" (mouseover)="displayInsightDropDown();" (mouseleave)="hideInsightDropDown();">INSIGHTS</a>
  <a [routerLinkActive]="['navbar-links-active']" [routerLink]="['explore']">EXPLORE</a>
  <a [routerLinkActive]="['navbar-links-active']" [routerLink]="['aboutus']">ABOUT</a>
</div>
```

Here is a picture of the result:

[image]

As you can see the arrow is positioned to the left, but never the center.

Any suggestions would help, thank you in advance.

Comment: Add this style to that :after element, and you're done...
#navbar .navbar-links a:after {
    left:0;
    right:0;
    margin:auto;
}

Comment: @KunalKhatri unfortunately this positioned the arrow for all the elements in the center of that entire `div`. Maybe this would work if all anchor tags were wrapped in `div` tags?

Comment: You're right, you need to wrap all the anchors in divs and place that arrow inside each wrappers...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the context for the absolutely positioned `::after`. To do so, add a non `static` position (`position: relative` in this case) to the `<a>` tags.

To center the `::after` element, I've used `left: calc(50% - 10px)` because the width of the arrow is known (`20px`). If to arrow can have variable size, you can use:

```
left: 50%;
transform: translateX(-50%);
```

```css
.navbar-links {
  margin-left: 10em;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0em 4em 0em 1em;
  min-width: 348px;
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
}

.navbar-links a {
  position: relative; /** the absolute context **/
  
  display: block;
  float: left;
  color: grey;
  padding: 14px 20px 14px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
}

.navbar-links a:hover::after {
  left: calc(50% - 10px);
  
  position: absolute;
  content: ' ';
  bottom: -10px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-width: 10px 10px 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: grey transparent;
  display: block;
  content: ' ';
}

body {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar-links">
  <a href="#">INSIGHTS</a>
  <a href="#">EXPLORE</a>
  <a href="#">ABOUT</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Although answer is accepted but I've another solution using `flex` property of CSS, add two line inside `.navbar-links a`

```
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
```

no need for calculation

```css
.navbar-links {
      margin-left: 10em;
      height: 100%;
      padding: 0em 4em 0em 1em;
      min-width: 348px;
      margin-top: auto;
      margin-bottom: auto;
    }

    .navbar-links a {
      position: relative;
      /** the absolute context **/

      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      float: left;
      color: grey;
      padding: 14px 20px 14px 20px;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 14px;
      margin-top: auto;
      margin-bottom: auto;
    }

    .navbar-links a:hover::after {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: -10px;
      width: 0;
      height: 0;
      border-width: 10px 10px 0;
      border-style: solid;
      border-color: grey transparent;
      content: ' ';
    }

    body {
      overflow: hidden;
    }
```

```html
<div class="navbar-links">
  <a href="#">INSIGHTS</a>
  <a href="#">EXPLORE</a>
  <a href="#">ABOUT</a>
</div>
```